# Present Perfect or other tenses at he closing of a broadcast (show)?

Tags: tense-agreement

At the end of a broadcast the presenter often says:"It's been "Bridge to English". All the best and see you soon!"

If it were to be put across with a single sentense noting the name of the presenter performed by himself, which of the following patterns would be working good?

1. It's Ed Sullivan who has presented this show for you. See you soon!
2. It was Ed Sullivan who has presented this show for you. See you soon!
3. It's Ed Sullivan who presented this show for you. See you soon!
4. It was Ed Sullivan who had presented this show for you. See you soon!
5. It was Ed Sullivan who presented this show for you. See you soon!

Comment: Probably "The presenter was me, Ed Sullivan." In recent years I've noticed a tendency on BBC radio for presenters of light entertainment programmes to say "I have been [Ed Sullivan]" - as though they are no longer that person now the show has finished!

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you! To me, as a non-native speaker, it would seem that PrPerf. is a very luscious tense helping to express oneself neatly and precisely. I like it conveying the idea of recurrent (repeated) events or actions in the period leading up to the present. Maybe "I've been Ed Sullivan" means that "I have appeared for a good few times in the show (which hasn't finished yet but finishes in some seconds)?

Comment: None of the rephrasings sound natural to me.  The phrasing "This has been ____" is so idiomatic at this point that anything else sounds very odd.

Comment: @stangdon Would using different pronouns that are similar in meaning make difference: "It has been____" or "That has been____"?

Comment: @Eugene No, neither of them sound more natural.  If I heard "It has been" or "That has been", I would ask "**What** has been?"